# I can't move /var folder to other partition

Tags: linux, partition

I am trying to move the `/var` folder to another (bigger) partition but I get stuck on the error message

> device or resource busy

I have done every step such as creating a new mount for the new folder and copying the contents of the `/var` folder to it as well as setting up runlevel to 1 (through `init 1`).

I don't know what else to do, I even killed the process that is making it busy but when I kill them I am unable to type on terminal again to finish the operation.

Comment: Please elaborate on "every step". Which steps did you do exactly? Apart from that: Can you bring the system down and do the changes while it is offline (accessing its drive from another system i.e. live boot)?

Comment: I'm afraid that the simplest way is to prep the new partition, including changing fstab, and rebooting.

Comment: Use `lsof` to see open files, but since `/var` is used for lots of state stuff like pidfiles you're going to have to shut down a lot to do all of /var.  Consider moving only the big parts of var ( you haven't told us what that is, but say /var/log or docker files) .  Easier to stay up that way.  Be careful with this, there might be some boot time deps on /var being there

Comment: Boot from a live distro to delete your old `/var` and change `/etc/fstab` to mount your new partition to `/var`.  That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not at all certain that modern Linux distributions support having `/` and `/var` on different filesystems...

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try to be more clear, I appreciate the tips. I'll go through step by step of the commands I made.

Answer (score 1):

In contrary to your belief, it is possible for System V runlevel 1 (a la `init 1`) to have some running services, which may hog your `/var` directory.

Since you neither elaborate on which kind of system/distribution you are using, nor give `ps auxfww` output; I'm going give a generic, sure-fire— but also dirty and *dodgy* advice...

---

To boot a GNU/Linux system **without *any* program but your shell**, boot your machine with `init=/bin/sh` parameter appended to the end of *kernel* command line.

Without *any* other program running, this is an ideal environment to commence your `/var` relocation operation.

But there are few things you need to take note of...

- Beware that this is a *dodgy* thing to do, only resort to this if it cannot be done in other ways.
- The shell will be a root shell, and likely to have neither command history nor line editing.
- Only one console will be available; no pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F2</kbd> if you got stuck.
- Job control will not work; no pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to stop runaway program.
- `$HOME` directory location will be set to `/` (rather than the usual `/root`); so avoid doing things that write to your home directory.
- Do not `exit` from your main shell. (Doing so will halt your system with kernel panic)

And don't forget these operational safety procedure...

- Once booted in this environment, before doing anything, run `mount -o rw,remount /` to make sure that that root filesystem is writable.
- Once you are done with your business...

  1. Make sure to un-mount any extra filesystems you mounted.
  2. Make sure you re-mount root filesystem read-only: `mount -o ro,remount /`
  3. Make sure you flush all disk cache: `sync`
  4. Then force-reset the system: `reboot -f` (pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> also works)

A less-dodgy alternative is booting your system with a GNU/Linux boot disk, and do your moving operations from there of course.

Comment: I think booting into a initrd "hook" is also a possibility. Then you have busybox instead of pid 1 shell. In a situation like this, a small second installation can also be useful - if you have it already. Insetad of remounting root from "inside", you just mount that partition from "outside". Same idea as markgraf's live distro.

Comment: "GNU/Linux boot disk": disk? like floppy disk? ;) You mean live distro? Oh sorry you mean "compact disk" = "Live CD".  Today: USB.